# Build protobuf for python3 on linux mint 16

Tags: linux, python-3.x, build, protocol-buffers, linux-mint

I'm having troubles building protocol buffers for python 3 found at https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf. According to instructions, I have to run following commands to install the library:

```
  $ ./configure
  $ make
  $ make check
  $ make install
```

The problem is that, when I execute ./configure (in library's folder of course), I get an error saying: bash: **./configure: No such file or directory**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling directly from git rather than a release package, you first must run `./autogen.sh`.